# Dictionary not rendering in page

Tags: django

in my view im trying to pass in a dictionary like so

```
rooms = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'designign'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'wow'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'now'},
]

def home(request):
    context = {'rooms' : rooms}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Then in my home.html page i have this code

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Home Template</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        {% for room in rooms %}
            <div>
                <h1>{{room.name}}</h1>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

but the items in the dictionary are not displaying.

the url and path are fine because
`<h1>Home Template</h1>` displays

but nothing else displays

**main.html**

```
<body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

urlpattern if that matters

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home")
]
```

Comment: What if you restart the server?

Comment: Could you please restart your server as @WillemVanOnsem suggested, it should work fine. as I dont see any issue in it.

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain I've restarted the server and nothing. I can change the top h1 and the page updates but anything inside the for loop doesn't render

Comment: just try to print {{rooms}} on your template outside of for loop and check the output

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary items are not accessed as attributes.

Try doing

```
room["name" ]
```

Comment: In Django templates we can access the dict items using (.) DOT